# i18next not detecting language variation, eg: en-us

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, translation, i18next, react-i18next

When I set in my browser a language variation, for example: *English (United States) / en-us*. The i18next library doesn't detect that variation and just loads the next language in the list, for example: Spanish or plain English.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make **i18Next** detect language variations, you have to add: `nonExplicitSupportedLngs: true,` in the i18next config file, for example:

```
i18next
    ...
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .init({
        supportedLngs: ['en', 'es'],
        nonExplicitSupportedLngs: true, //support language variation
        ...
    });
```

Reference: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options > *nonExplicitSupportedLngs*

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the `supportedLngs` option or add `nonExplicitSupportedLngs: true`.